# django - Q object that don't assert if one or more fields don't exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, django-q

Lets say I have the following models:

```
Model A:
    date
    category
    something
    ...
```

and:

```
Model B:
    date
    category
    ...
```

I want to create a single Q object that will filter by `date`, `category`, and `something`, but only if it exists in the model I apply the filter on.

In other words, a single `Q` that I can apply on both `A` and `B` models, just that with `B` the `something` filter will be ignored since this field doesn't exist in `B`.

If I try a naive implementation, eg a `Q` with `date`, `category` and `something` in it, when applied on `B` model I get the following error:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'something' into field. Choices are...`

Which makes sense since B really don't have a field named `something` in it. But I want to change that behavior and make it work and just ignore the non-existing field instead of throwing an exception.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. However, you can write a function that inspects the model's fields, and generates the appropriate Q object. Something like:

```
def content_query(model, value):
    allowed = ['date', 'category', 'something']
    model_fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields and f.name in allowed]

    return Q(**{f: value for f in model_fields})
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution! What I ended up doing was a dictionary of queries where the model type is the key and the value is slightly different Q, but I like the method you suggested. I will try it out next time I write Q objects for these models.